# How to dynamically decide which static class to use

Tags: c#, oop

We have a large class that contains a bunch of css selectors stored as static strings. Example:

```
public class Constants
}
    public static string Selector1 = "#someID";
    public static string Selector2 = ".some.classes a";
    // and so on...
}
```

We now need to test a different version of our web app which requires a few different selectors. So we need to find a clean scalable way to override these selectors based on some configuration.

My solution to the problem is this: I'm trying to create a `BaseConstants` class which will have the current set of selectors. Then I create another class called `UpdatedConstants` which will subclass the `BaseConstants` class. This class will then contian all the selectors and just override the ones that need changing with the `new` keyword. Example:

```
public class UpdatedConstants : BaseConstants
{
    // Overrides the base class's Selector1 string
    public new static string Selector1 = "#someOtherID";
}
```

This works well for overriding the strings however I'm stumped as to how the project will decide which static class to use when it is compiled. All our existing code uses the `Constants` class like this:
`var element = driver.GetElement(Constants.SomeSelector);`

Is there a way to dynamically decide which class is the final `Constants` class? Perhaps by some meta-programming magic?

Let me know if anyone has questions or needs a better explanation of the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your constants classes non-static and use a singleton. This also lets you use virtual properties, since you want to use a base Constants class.

```
public static class Constants
{
    static Constants()
    {
#if FOO
        Current = new ConstantsFoo();
#elif BAR
        Current = new ConstantsBar();
#endif
    }

    public static ConstantsBase Current { get; private set; }
}

//...snip

var element = driver.GetElement(Constants.Current.SomeSelector);
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution, although I'd like it even better if I could get away with not adding the `.Current` part to everything. Do you think there's  a way to avoid adding that piece?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You could define an extension method of Object: `public static class Extensions { public static ConstantsBase Consts(this object obj) => Constants.Current; }`, then use `Consts().SomeSelector`. I don't know how much I like that idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change all occurences `Constants.SomeSelector`, the only way to have different behavoirs is using pre-processor directives in the `Constants` class:

```
public class Constants
}
#if OLD
    public static string Selector1 = "#someID";
#elif NEW
    public static string Selector1 = "#someNewID";
#endif
    public static string Selector2 = ".some.classes a";
    // and so on...
}
```

Else you can use the approach from Ed Plunketts answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, probably not what you're looking for, but... You might want to consider *not* doing it like this.

Put it this way - if you travel down the road, what will your code look like in 5 years?  You'll have a base class that contains your original settings, a subclass for how they were modified the first time (when you asked this question), a subclass inheriting from *that* subclass on how they were modified the next time, and so on.  I could easily imagine 10 subclasses in a giant chain - and if you wanted to trace the current value for any setting, you'd have to travel up that chain until you found where it was most recently set/overriden.  It sounds like a maintenance nightmare, to be honest.

If I were in your shoes, this is what the new code would look like:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static string Selector1 { get { return ReadFromSettings("Selector1"); } }
    public static string Selector2 { get { return ReadFromSettings("Selector2"); } }
    //etc
    // then, code for ReadFromSettings()
}
```

... and then migrate those settings into an actual settings file.  Nobody needs to change any code on the calling end (they still reference Constants.Selector1) - except, instead of having this all hard-coded in a series of derived classes, you just have a file with your values.

Comment: I understand your concern although I think it can be avoided with some organization and judiciously choosing when to subclass. I'm envisioning that the `BaseConstants` class would contain the most up to date css selectors. Any subclasses would be for a specific version of our web app. If you follow this paradigm then chaining issue goes away and you're left with discrete versions of css selectors which work with the version you're testing against. Although this approach doesn't guarantee that organization I think it would handle the maintenance nightmare, no?

Comment: I think some of the nightmare might be shifted then.  I mean, imagine you're about to change the BaseConstants to be the new version.  You can't just change it, because each derived class represents a specific version - and those derived classes are assuming certain values from your base class.  If "VersionRemoteOnly" *doesn't* override "MySetting1" because the base class' MySetting1 is what it needs, you can't go in and change MySetting1 in your current class because it'll break "VersionRemoveOnly".

Comment: Is there any particular reason you wouldn't want to go to a Settings/Config based approach?